# Array $_POST without using multiple input fields

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I was wondering if it's possible to receive arrays in $_POST but with a single input field in the html and without sending the form with ajax?

Normally I would do this

```
<input type="hidden" name="array[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="array[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="array[]" />
.............
```

I was thinking of something like this

```
<input type="array" name="array" value="1,2,3,4" / >
```

Comment: If you mean with receive in php, then no! How should php get the data or should even know from where and when it should grab data?! php is server side, so how do you want to get the data to the server without submitting a form or ajax?! weird it voodoo?!

Comment: As long as you have a known pattern you can always create an array from the value..

Comment: ok I knew that. but I was just wondering if there's some support for array already, so I don't have to make those extra steps

Comment: I would generate the hidden inputs using a PHP array, that way its a little more dynamic. Then using PHP it will feel more like an array of html inputs

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to `explode()` the value to get an array:

```
$arrayOfInputs = explode(',', $_GET['array']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You *must* have multiple input fields to submit in the normal way.  However, you can generate those with JavaScript.

Add an on-submit handler to the form, and then have JavaScript append the necessary input elements to the form right before submission.

I'd provide sample code, but you didn't specify *how* that array would be built.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index notation

```
$_POST['array1'][0] //first element in the array
$_POST['array1'][1] // the second
$_POST['array1'][2] // the third
```

or you can use loop

```
for ($i = 0, $l = count($_POST['array1']); $i < $l; $i++) {
    doStuff($_POST['array1'][$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not support array, so all the value of HTML input field is a plain text. so at first you have to explode the value of array field

```
$arrayOfInputs = explode(',', $_GET['array']);
```

and use them

```
echo $arrayOfInputs[0];
echo $arrayOfInputs[1];
echo $arrayOfInputs[2];
```

Hope you will understand